# how to search common column used in different tables of a database and update it?

Tags: sql

How to search common column used in different tables of a database and update?
Thanks

Comment: What's a "common column" supposed to be? Please be more specific

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Update how? The column data or the column name?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE1
       JOIN TABLE2
       ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
SET    TABLE1.ID = "SOME VALUE";
```

Comment: That's product specific SQL, and no dbms is specified here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='your column name'
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the question ask about something else. That's one of the many reasons why answers are better if they do explain the solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will go a long way towards helping current and future readers understand your answer even better.

Comment: distinct not needed, since a table can only have max one column with the column name asked for.